# Catch the "DONE" click on ios - while hiding the keyboard in angular app

Tags: ios, angularjs

I'm using AngularJS. 
And I want to catch the event when the user close the keyboard by clicking the "done" button.

The ng-keypress doesn't catch this event.
and The ng-blue catch it, But I don't want all the blur (or unfocused) Just the done click.

[image]